# Freemarker case insensitive comparison

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to check if a variable contains a string and I want the comparison to be case-insensitive.

This is what I have:

<#if Recipient.contact.jobtitle[0]?contains("marketing")>
You're receiving this because you're in marketing.
<#else>
You don't seem to be in marketing.

But it doesn't work if the job title contains 'Marketing'.

What do I do to make the comparison case-insensitive?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Add `?lower_case` before `?contains` ...